# How to dismiss keyboard after pressing the "X" in searchview? (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, androidx

I want to dismiss the keyboard upon entering the activity and after the person searches and press "X" on the searchview. how do i do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can set searchView close button OnClickListener using this code:-

```
//finding the close button Id
int ClsBtn = searchView.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
//Get close button by its id
ImageView ClsImg = (ImageView) this.searchView.findViewById(ClsBtn);
//Onclick listener
ClsImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //hide the keyboard
InputMethodManager inputM = (InputMethodManager)                                 getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
if(inputM != null){
        inputM.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).